# count same string in an array in php

Tags: php

I have an array that contains values with the same string, how will I able to count those same string into a number.

example array:

```
$animals = array('dog','dog','cat','mouse','cat');
```

output:

```
dog x2,
cat x2,
mouse x1
```

Comment: Might not be the most elegant or efficient solution, but how about sorting the array, then iterating over it and checking the current element against the previous one and holding counters in a mapping?

Comment: i want to get not only the number of duplicate string, but also the string itself, ex. dog x2

Comment: @nikko Number of duplicates or occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `foreach()` with `array_count_values()` like this

```
$animals = array('dog','dog','cat','mouse','cat');
$values=array_count_values($animals) ;
foreach ($values as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key ."X". $value;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for, thank you

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Use  `array_count_values`

```
$animals = array('dog','dog','cat','mouse','cat');
$count_values = array_count_values($animals);

print_r($count_values );
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [dog] => 2
    [cat] => 2
    [mouse] => 1
)
```

And Iterate it over like this

```
foreach($occurences as $key => $item){
    echo $key ." x" .$item .",";
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: @nikko I've updated my answer please look at foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

This would do:

```
// The verbose way
<?php
   $counts = [];
   $animals = array('dog','dog','cat','mouse','cat');

   foreach ($animals as $value) {
       if (key_exists($value, $counts)) {
           $counts[$value] += 1;
       } else {
           $counts[$value] = 1;
       }
   }
?>
```

...but php has a method that does exactly that

```
<?php
    $counts = array_count_values($animals);
?>
```

and later, if you want to print the occurences

```
foreach ($counts as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." x".$value."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array =  array('dog','dog','cat','mouse','cat');
$vals = array_count_values($array);
// print_r($vals);
foreach ($vals as $key=>$value) {
  echo $key ." X". $value;
  echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, BTW i want to get not only the number of duplicate string, but also i want to print the string , ex. dog x2

Comment: Add some description to your answer.